# Why would one provision a VPC using a cidr outside the private IPv4 address spaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I see that AWS allows one to create a VPC with a cidr that can be outside the private IPv4 address space, but why would one ever do so?

Comment: Sometimes you want a public server, sometimes you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone chooses a non private IP range CIDR for their VPC, it could be:

- For convenience
- Run out of CIDRs, if you keep allocating /16
- For testing. I remember a setup where the CIDR overlapped Microsoft's. They did it to route the traffic that was supposed to go to Microsoft was routed internally for analyzing the data
- When a non private IP range CIDR is used, traffic is never routed from outside AWS into the VPC because no router will have a route to the VPC. It is only for internal routing
- If you have only a private subnet (with customer gateway to connect to your corporate network) - a.k.a [Scenario 4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario4.html), you can have any CIDR range.

Comment: I could see that being the case, if you allocated resources in AWS with non private IP range CIDR and connecting them to your corporate network.

Answer (score 1):

This is available in order to host a public network and although surprising, there are organizations that use public IP space for their internal network. These are primarily organizations that own a massive amount of public IP space. This is typically a carryover from the early days of the internet.

From the [AWS VPC FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/)

> Q. What IP address ranges can I use within my VPC?
>
> You can use any IPv4 address range, including RFC 1918 or publicly
>   routable IP ranges for the primary CIDR block. For the secondary CIDR
>   blocks certain restrictions apply. Publicly routable IP blocks are
>   only reachable via the Virtual Private Gateway and cannot be accessed
>   over the Internet through the Internet gateway. AWS does not advertise
>   customer-owned IP address blocks to the Internet. You can allocate an
>   Amazon-provided IPv6 CIDR block to a VPC by calling the relevant API
>   or via the AWS Management Console.

As I mentioned, cases where this would typically be seen is if an organization owns a set of public IP space and use those IP addresses on their internal network. This would then allow traffic from the internal network to communicate via Direct Connect to network interfaces in the VPC. This is a very uncommon scenario but is why this exists.

While it may be uncommon, some of the largest companies in the world, which acquired massive amounts of IPv4 addresses in the early to mid 90s, are still migrating their internal network to RFC-1918 space. I suspect these large potential customers also drove AWS to support public address space in this way. Keep in mind that RFC-1918 didn't exist until 1996 and even then it wasn't broadly adopted.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_assigned_/8_IPv4_address_blocks

Comment: But aren't VPC's private by default. How would one make their block of public IP's routable into AWS?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#vpc-public-ipv4-addresses

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario1.html

Comment: These two documents still only explain the use of private cidrs for VPC's. Trying to find a reason where one might provision something like 8.8.0.0/16. An instance in that vpc wouldn't then be able to interact with say Google's DNS at 8.8.8.8

Comment: The valid use cases for this are very rare, @mhumesf.

Comment: @BryceH Thanks! Nice to see some official documentation with details on the subject